# Boogie strange assert(false) behavior

Tags: z3, dafny

I am working with Boogie and I have come across some behaviors I do not understand.

I have been using `assert(false)` as a way to check if the previous `assume` statements are absurd.

For instance in the following case, the program is verified without errors...

```
type T;
const t1, t2: T;
procedure test()
{
  assume (t1 == t2);
  assume (t1 != t2);
  assert(false);
}
```

...as `t1 == t2 && t1 != t2` is an absurd statement.

On the other hand if I have something like

```
type T;
var map: [T]bool;
const t1, t2: T;

procedure test()
{
  assume(forall a1: T, a2: T :: !map[a1] && map[a2]);
  //assert(!map[t1]);
  assert(false);
}
```

The `assert(false)` only fails when the commented line is uncommented. Why is the commented assert changing the result of the `assert(false)`?

Comment: I am not sure about this but when you say ```assume(t1 == t2)``` and ```assume(t1 != t2)```, if you combine those two it would say ```assume(t1 == t2 && t1 != t2) ==> assume(false)``` because that statement on the left side would never be true. As a result says that assume false is true. That's why ```assert(false)``` won't fail.

Comment: And I believe that you want to say 'only fails when the commented line is **commented**' not uncommented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gist: the SMT solver underlying Boogie will not instantiate the quantifier if you don't mention a ground instance of `map[...]` in your program.

Here is why: SMT solvers (that use e-matching) typically use syntactic heuristics to decide when to instantiate a quantifier. Consider the following quantifier:

```
forall i: Int :: f(i)
```

This quantifier admits infinitely many instantiations (since `i` ranges over an unbounded domain), trying all would thus result in non-termination. Instead, SMT solvers expect syntactic hints instructing it for which `i` the quantifier should be instantiated. These hints are called a *patterns* or *triggers*. In Boogie, they can be written as follows:

```
forall i: Int :: {f(i)} f(i)
```

This trigger instructs the SMT solver to instantiate the quantifier for each `i` for which `f(i)` is mentioned in the program (or rather, current proof search). E.g., if you assume `f(5)`, then the quantifier will be instantiated with `5` substituted for `i`.

In your example, you don't provide a pattern explicitly, so the SMT solver might pick one for you, by inspecting the quantifier body. It will most likely pick `{map[a1], map[a2]}` (multiple function applications are allowed, patterns must cover all quantified variables). If you uncomment the assume, the ground term `map[t1]` becomes available, and the SMT solver can instantiate the quantifier with `a1, a2` mapped to `t1, t1`. Hence, the contradiction is obtained.

See the [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide) for more details on patterns. More involved texts about patterns can be found, e.g. in
[this paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/krml253.pdf), in
[this paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/rmkrml183.pdf) or in
[this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1670416).